# retrieving records with concat statement in sql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i have this query and i want to concat the names of the student. Where should I put the concat statement?

> "concat(text,LPAD(id,4,'0'))"

The text and id here is from students table. this is the query:

```
"SELECT p.*, s.* FROM students s, payments p  
 where s.id=p.id and level='Grade 3' and amount>='1500'"
```

Table

-students table-

```
create table students(
    text char(5)NOT NULL,
    id int(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(250),
    address varchar(250)
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

-payments-

```
create table payments(
    p_id int(11)NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    amount varchar(250),
    id int,
    PRIMARY KEY(p_id)
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES students(id);
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 SELECT p.*, s.*, concat(s.text,LPAD(s.id,4,'0')) as student_names 
 FROM students s, payments p  
 where s.id=p.id and level='Grade 3' and amount>='1500'
```